# Dropdown Menu of Twitter Bootstrap doesn't work -- doesn't unfold

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in my web app and have included `bootstrap.css/js` files. But when I click on `menu base` it doesn't unfold and nothing happens.

Any idea what is wrong? Here is my code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu base</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="more-drop">
         <li class="dropdown-menuitem">
               <a href="/page1">sub menu1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="dropdown-menuitem">
               <a href="/page2">sub menu2</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you include also jQuery? Bootstrap's js requires jQuery.

Comment: kindly also mention bootstrap versoin?

Comment: @yuriy636, v3.3.2

Comment: @JazibBashir, yes.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Make sure loading jQuery before Bootstrap's JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working Code:

Working Fiddle: [Dropdown Menu Fix](https://jsfiddle.net/jazibbashir/DTcHh/24219/)

**Mistake**:

1- Dropdown Menu 'aria-labelledby' is not defined

2- Anchor Tag ID is not set with 'aria-labelledby' value

**aria-labelledby**: Identifies the element (or elements) that labels the current element.

```
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="dropdownMenu1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu base</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="more-drop" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li class="dropdown-menuitem">
            <a href="/page1">sub menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-menuitem">
            <a href="/page2">sub menu2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the following attributes necessary for *Bootstrap* dropdown to work as toggle dropdown menu.

- role="button"
- aria-haspopup="true"
- aria-expanded="false"

### Code Snippet

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helps you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dropdown menu of twitter bootstrap doesn't work — doesn't unfold</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> menu base <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">sub menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```